# Send email confirmation through JavaScript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want an email to be sent to users that register on my app (just a test app) to which they will receive an email of confirmation.

I am not quite sure how to go about this but I would have thought that I would need to implement some javascript within the register function?

I have posted my JavaScript and HTML code that is involved in the registration process, so I would much appreciate any assistance here.

(Using HTML, JavaScript, Phonegap, JQueryMobile)

Thanks.

HTML -

```
 <form onsubmit="registerUser(); return false;">
        <label for="txtusername">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtusername">   <input type="submit" value="Check Availability" data-mini="true" onclick="return CheckUser()">
        <br>
        <label for="txtfirstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtfirstname">
        <label for="txtlastname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtlastname" >
        <label for="txtemail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="txtemail" >
        <label for="txtpassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtpassword" >
        <label for="passwordconfirm">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="passwordconfirm" >
        <input type="submit" value="Register User">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return DeleteUser()">
    </form>
```

JavaScript -

```
 function registerUser() {
       var Username = document.getElementById("txtusername").value;
       var Firstname = document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value;
       var Lastname = document.getElementById("txtlastname").value;
       var Email = document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
       var Password = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
       var Confirmpass = document.getElementById("passwordconfirm").value;

         db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2*1024*1024);
         db.transaction(function(tx) {
          NewUser(tx, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Confirmpass);
          }, errorRegistration, successRegistration);
          }

          function NewUser(tx, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Confirmpass) {
          var _Query = ("INSERT INTO SoccerEarth(UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, CPass) values ('"+ Username +"','"+ Firstname +"','"+ Lastname +"','"+ Email +"', '"+ Password +"', '"+ Confirmpass +"')");
           alert(_Query);
           tx.executeSql(_Query);
           }
           function errorRegistration(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert(error, null, "Got an error mate", "cool");
            }
           function successRegistration() {
           navigator.notification.alert("User data has been registered", null, "Information", "ok");
             $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page4" );
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript running in the browser cannot send emails. You sumbit the data to the server, which can construct and send the emails. The database should also be on the server. Since this is a test app you can use Apache, MySQL, and PHP running on your computer. For a production app you would normally rent a server or use a backend as a service.

Comment: So how do I go about that?

Comment: @Mahdi there is no easy answer

Comment: @Mahdi Apache + MySQL + PHP running on a server should be fine but there are a million other ways

Comment: Ok thanks, is it a difficult process or can it be done quite simply and quickly?

Comment: @Mahdi it will take time if you have not done it before (at least 3 hours)

Comment: @Madhi if this answered your question, can you accept it

Comment: I'm hoping to get a little more assistance in terms of where I should start rather than just a brief comment on what I can use in order to do it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107414/discussion-between-user104317-and-mahdi).